# Displaying Advanced Custom Field (ACF) value in a WooCommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, product

I want to display the value from an Advanced Custom Field (ACF) in Woocommerce and I am using this code in this function hooked:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'charting', 20 );

function charting() {
    if( get_field('size_chart') ) { 
       echo '<p><a href="'.the_field('size_chart').'" data-rel="prettyPhoto">size guide</a></p>';
    }
    return;
}
```

But it is not working, it is displaying the custom field value above the href (size guide) and the href is empty like this:

```
<a href="" data-rel="prettyPhoto">size guide</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure the value has been saved? What do you get if you `var_dump(the_field('size_chart'));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't use `echo` with ACF [`the_field('my_field')`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) , because when using [`the_field('my_field')`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)  is just like using [`echo get_field('my_field')`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), so you are trying to `echo` an `echo`. Instead use [`get_field('my_field')`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) this way in your code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'charting', 20 );

function charting() {
    if( !empty( get_field('size_chart') ) ) { // if your custom field is not empty…
        echo '<p><a href="' . get_field('size_chart') . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto">size guide</a></p>';
    }
    return;
}
```

After, I have add `empty()` function in your condition…

You can also try to `return` it instead of `echo`:

```
    return '<p><a href="' . get_field('size_chart') . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto">size guide</a></p>';
```

Reference:

- [ACF the_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)
- [ACF get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Answer (score 1):

I used this code and it worked well in local but when i upload function file in server it doesn,t work and it gives server error 500, so I had to remove this code again